# How to control newline and indent when export to LaTeX from org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have a test org-mode file as below:

```
#+OPTIONS: ':nil *:t -:nil ::nil <:nil H:3 \n:nil ^:{} arch:headline
#+OPTIONS: author:nil c:nil creator:nil d:(not "LOGBOOK") date:t e:t
#+OPTIONS: email:nil f:t inline:t num:t p:nil pri:nil prop:nil stat:t
#+OPTIONS: tags:t tasks:t tex:t timestamp:t title:t toc:t todo:t |:t
#+LANGUAGE: en
#+SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+CREATOR: Emacs 25.0.50.1 (Org mode 8.3.1)

* Indent and Newline Test

  First line.

  Second line.
```

When I export it to pdf with `C-c C-e l p', it generate a pdf file looks like this:

```
First line.
    Second line.
```

But what I expect is not indent on the second line and a newline between these two lines.

```
First line.

Second line.
```

Would anyone show me how could I achieve that?

Ugly solution:

After read the post mentioned by @wvxvw , I temporarily get a `very ugly' solution for it.

I have to code my content in LaTeX syntax as below:

```
First line.
\\
\\
Second line.
```

Then it exports as what I expected. (But the org file looks really ugly)

Comment: Are you sure something else is not going wrong?  I get the same as you are expecting.  Try exporting from a [minimal setup](http://orgmode.org/manual/Feedback.html#Feedback).

Comment: See second answer for immediate solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section. Technically, this is considered to be the "correct" default, but many people find it strange too.

Comment: @wvxvw Ah! I thought the OP was talking about the exported latex source, not the actual pdf :-p.

Comment: @suvayu I did try it on minimal setup. Still get the indent line version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two methods depending on whether you would like to have no indents in the file at all or only prevent specific lines from being indented. Both methods use the latex code insertion discussed here: https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html

1) File-wide no indents

At the top of your org file you could insert:

```
#+LATEX: \setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

2) No-indent for specific lines

At the start of lines that should not be indented you could insert:

```
@@latex:\noindent@@
```

Make sure to leave a trailing space after this though
Example:

```
First line.

@@latex:\noindent@@ Second line.
```

It also works by putting them in two lines

```
First Line.

@@latex:\noindent@@
Second line.
```

Comment: Is there a way to set all paragraphs after `begin_latex` to no indentation?